# Unable to use stack channel logging in Laravel

Tags: laravel, logging, gelf

I'm unable to use 'stack' channel logging, hoping you can help.

In my Laravel (9.x) project, I've setup a 'gelf' channel that logs to my Graylog. I want logs both in Graylog and in `storage/logs/laravel.log`

My `config/logging.php`:

```php
'default' => 'stack',

'channels' => [
        'stack' => [
            'driver' => 'stack',
            'channels' => ['single', 'gelf'],
            'ignore_exceptions' => false,
        ],

        'single' => [
            'driver' => 'single',
            'path' => storage_path('logs/laravel.log'),
            'level' => env('LOG_LEVEL', 'debug'),
        ],

        'gelf' => [
            'driver' => 'custom',
            ...
        ]
]
```

In this configuration, I ONLY get log output in `laravel.log`. If I set `channels.stack.channels` to ['single'], I of course still get output to `laravel.log`. If I set `channels.stack.channels` to ['gelf'], nothing happens. If I change `default` to 'gelf', then I get Graylog logging, but of course, nothing in `laravel.log`.

##### What am I possibly missing? I don't see others on Google with this issue.

---

###### Troubleshooting attempts:

- I've done `php artisan config:cache` on every change, so have ruled out caching issues.
- As a temporary work-around, I've just set it to 'gelf' and registered a reportable in the `App\Exceptions\Handler::register()` method for the single channel:

```
public function register():void
{
    $this->reportable(function (Throwable $e) {
        Log::channel('single')->warning($e);
    });
}
```

Comment: ```php artisan o:c``` may be helpful. If it won't work then run in sequence ```artisan config:cache``` ```artisan cache:clear``` ```artisan config:cache```. Or you can also ```dd``` in anywhere to get the config value ```dd(config('logging.channels.stack'))``` to validate the value